# Do I have to make a logout when using build and push command in docker task in azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and Push
  inputs:
    command: buildAndPush
    containerRegistry: dockerRegistryServiceConnection1
    repository: contosoRepository
    tags: |
      tag1
```

A convenience command called buildAndPush allows for build and push of images to container registry in a single command. See the above snippet

**Question:**

Do I need to log out from the container registry by adding following task?

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Logout of ACR
  inputs:
    command: logout
    containerRegistry: dockerRegistryServiceConnection1
```

Comment: Are you explicitly logging into the container registry using the `login` command in a task before your `buildAndPush` task?

Comment: @MichaelMurray no I didn't have the `login` step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion this is not necessary to login or logout.

You may even find an example in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops#how-we-build-your-pipeline) without login or logout:

```yaml
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build job
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

So you may wonder what actually login does. If you check a source code you will find that it actually set up `DOCKER_CONFIG` (The location of your client configuration files.)

```js
export function run(connection: ContainerConnection): any {
    var defer = Q.defer<any>();
    connection.setDockerConfigEnvVariable();   
    defer.resolve(null);
    return defer.promise;
}
```

and what `logout` does ;)

```js
export function run(connection: ContainerConnection): any {
    // logging out is being handled in connection.close() method, called after the command execution.
    var defer = Q.defer<any>();
    defer.resolve(null);
    return <Q.Promise<any>>defer.promise;
}
```

So how does it work?

```js
// Connect to any specified container registry
let connection = new ContainerConnection();
connection.open(null, registryAuthenticationToken, true, isLogout);

let dockerCommandMap = {
    "buildandpush": "./dockerbuildandpush",
    "build": "./dockerbuild",
    "push": "./dockerpush",
    "login": "./dockerlogin",
    "logout": "./dockerlogout"
}

let telemetry = {
    command: command,
    jobId: tl.getVariable('SYSTEM_JOBID')
};

console.log("##vso[telemetry.publish area=%s;feature=%s]%s",
    "TaskEndpointId",
    "DockerV2",
    JSON.stringify(telemetry));

/* tslint:disable:no-var-requires */
let commandImplementation = require("./dockercommand");
if (command in dockerCommandMap) {
    commandImplementation = require(dockerCommandMap[command]);
}

let resultPaths = "";
commandImplementation.run(connection, (pathToResult) => {
    resultPaths += pathToResult;    
})
/* tslint:enable:no-var-requires */
.fin(function cleanup() {
    if (command !== "login") {
        connection.close(true, command);
    }
})
```

Starting `build` command you will

- connect to container registry
- run command
- close connection (if this is not a login command)

And this is what close connection does:

> If registry info is present, remove auth for only that registry. (This can happen for any command - build, push, logout etc.)
>   Else, remove all auth data. (This would happen only in case of logout command. For other commands, logout is not called.)

Answering your question, you can live without login and logout command.

Comment: I'm noticing that containers are left over in the "stopped" state.  Do we have to do an explicit `remove` of the container after the buildandpush?

Comment: I think that it could depend type of agent you use. If it is MS hosted no need for this. For self hosted I would recommend rather remove.